# Sharepoint 2013 Editing Default.aspx breaks permissions

Tags: 2013

I just took over SharePoint, and I'm still learning, so bear with me here...We have a subsite off of our main site that has a navigation menu above the quick launch menu that I can't seem to figure out how to edit without breaking the page.

[image]

As you can see, the "Documents" collapsible menu has a dark blue background, making it pretty much unreadable.  Now, I finally found where I can change this in the default.aspx, but if I so much as change a single character in the file using SharePoint designer, the page becomes locked to all but users with Contribute or Full Control access.  All other users get the "Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you" message.  If those users go to the /_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx page, they can see it fine.  I even copied the corrected default.aspx file to SitePages, and they can open it with /SitePages/default.aspx, and it shows up fine.  I set this as the homepage, but apparently there are links all over the place to the default.aspx directly, so that doesn't help much.

Anyone have any ideas that might help?  I'm open to anything that gets rid of the dark blue cell background without breaking anything else.

Update: Errors from ULS:

From the ULS logs:

Access denied.
SPRequest.GetFileAndFolderProperties: UserPrincipalName=i:0).w|s-1-5-21-1335564976-1893161414-1846952604-258528, AppPrincipalName= ,bstrUrl=http://SERVER/SUBSITE ,bstrStartUrl=default.aspx ,ListDocsFlags=16400 ,bThrowException=False

System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access denied., StackTrace:
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetFileOrFolderProperties(String strUrl, ListDocsFlags listDocsFlags, Boolean throwException, SPBasePermissions& permMask)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.PropertiesCore(Boolean throwException)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.get_Exists()
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.ServerWebApplication.Microsoft.Web.Design.Server.IServerWebApplication.GetProjectItemFromUrl(String url)
 at Microsoft.Web.Design.Server.ServerWebApplication.Microsoft.Web.Design.Interop.IFPACWebApplication.GetProjectItemFromUrl(String pszUrl)
 at Microsoft.Web.Design.DocumentDesigner.Microsoft.Web.Design.Interop.IWebDocumentDesigner.Initialize(IWebDocument document, IOleServiceProvider nativeServiceProvider, IWebRegisterDirectiveManager registerDirectiveManager)
 at Microsoft.Web.Design.Server.ServerDocument..ctor(String documentUrl, String webUrl, String contextUrl, IServerWebApplication webApplication)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.PageParser.CreateAndInitializeDocumentDesigner(String pageUrl, SPWeb web, String contextUrl, List`1 registerDirectiveDataList, MarkupOption markupOption, IServerWebApplication webApplication)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.CompressUsingMicrosoftWebDesigner(SourceContent sourceContent, String allRegisterDirectives)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.CompressInOrder(Deserializer firstMethod, Deserializer secondMethod, SourceContent sourceContent, String allRegisterDirectives, Boolean isClosed)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.CompressWebPartNoSave(Boolean isClosed)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.CreateWebPartsFromRowSetData(Boolean onlyInitializeClosedWebParts)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.LoadWebParts()
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.OnPageInitComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
 at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
 at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
 at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)

Access Denied. Exception: Access denied., StackTrace:
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndFolderProperties(String bstrUrl, String bstrStartUrl, ListDocsFlags ListDocsFlags, Boolean bThrowException, Int32& phrStatus, Object& pvarFiles, Object& pvarDirs, UInt32& pdwNumberOfFiles, UInt32& pdwNumberOfDirs)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndFolderProperties(String bstrUrl, String bstrStartUrl, ListDocsFlags ListDocsFlags, Boolean bThrowException, Int32& phrStatus, Object& pvarFiles, Object& pvarDirs, UInt32& pdwNumberOfFiles, UInt32& pdwNumberOfDirs).

Getting Error Message for Exception System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.CompressWebPartNoSave(Boolean isClosed)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.CreateWebPartsFromRowSetData(Boolean onlyInitializeClosedWebParts)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed without breaking the permissions.  I copied the default.aspx from the root of the site to SitePages via SharePoint Designer.  I then edited the copy in SitePages with SharePoint Designer and took out the bgcolor tag in that one spot.  I verified that I was able to get to the SitePages/default.aspx with my non-elevated account, and that the dark blue background was gone.  Then, I copied the corrected file back to the site root with SharePoint Designer, and everything worked properly.